# How to redirect user in profile dependency of type?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have some types of users. How to redirect user to profile dependency of account type?

After succesfull authorization I need to check `Auth::user()->type` and redirect to specified controller url.

I tried to use middleware for that:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            if(Auth::user()->type == "1"){
                return redirect('/center');
            }

           if(Auth::user()->type == "2"){
               return redirect('/doctor');
           }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

But where to call this middleware once?

Comment: Is there a reason you are writing it as middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define custom middleware for a specific route by doing this:

```
Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware('custom');
```

However, in this case since you just need to redirect the user after they login, I would recommend putting the logic at the end of your login method:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // handle authentication and return $user object if authenticated

    if ($user->type == "1") {
        return redirect('/center');
    } else if ($user->type == "2") {
        return redirect('/doctor');
    }

    // set default redirect if necessary
}
```

Comment: But it will work every time when I request this routing. So it will be loop redirect

Comment: @Blablacar that's why I would suggest adding the code to the controller method that authenticates your users. then it will only be run when a user logs in.